# Message when collection ends

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a trivia command for my bot and I want to make it so that it sends a message after the amount of time for the collection it says "Times up".
This is what I have written so far:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
exports.run = async(client, message, args) => {
  const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {
    time: 10000
  });
  number = 1;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  switch (random) {
    case 1:
      {
        message.channel.send("Case 1");
        collector.on('collect', message => {
          if (message.content == "1") {
            return message.channel.send("Correct!");
          } else {
            message.channel.send("wrong!");
          }
        });
        collector.on('end', message => {
          message.channel.send("times up!")
        });
      }
  }
};
```

When I do this it says send of undefined for the end event.

I've also tried this below, but it does nothing:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
exports.run = async(client, message, args) => {
  const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {
    time: 10000
  });
  number = 1;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  switch (random) {
    case 1:
      {
        message.channel.send("Case 1");

        collector.on('collect', message => {
          if (message.content == "1") {
            return message.channel.send("correct!");
          } else {
            message.channel.send("wrong!");
          }
        });
        collector.stop('end', message => {
          message.channel.send("times up!");
        });
      }
  }
};
```

The last thing I tried was this, but I got .stop of undefined:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
exports.run = async(client, message, args) => {
  const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {
    time: 10000
  });
  number = 1;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  switch (random) {
    case 1:
      {
        message.channel.send("Case 1");
        collector.on('collect', message => {
          if (message.content == "1") {
            return message.channel.send("correct!");
          } else {
            message.channel.send("wrong!");
          }
        }).stop(["times up"]);
      }
  }
};
```

Also, how could I make the collection stop after the "Correct!" spot?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
          message.channel.send("times up!")
        });
```

Like in the docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector?scrollTo=e-end